# JSTL inside javascript breaks if value is null

Tags: javascript, jstl

I have following JSTL code that I execute in javascript. It breaks if my first name value is null. How can I replace null value with blank?

```
       <script>
       <c:forEach var="rawData" items="${reportRawDataList}" varStatus="status">

       var aa='${rawData.visitor.firstName}';

       </c:forEach>
       </script>
```

Comment: The code (as posted here) is broken anyway; every declared JavaScript variable has the same name ("aa"). That aside, in what sense is it "broken"?

Answer (score 2):

The code you've posted looks highly suspicious. If there are more then one items in the list, then you'll get multiple repeated definitions of the same variable name.

Assuming you've abbreviated your code, you can just do this:

```
   var aa='${empty rawData.visitor.firstName ? "" : rawData.visitor.firstName}';
```

Comment: I tried but getting following error. SyntaxError: missing ; before statement

Comment: Its working now. I had to replace double quotes with single quotes. Thanks